# Select Rows with Values greater than V in more than C columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
Index   A   B   C   D
----------------------
1       2   0   0   10
2       0   3   6   0
3       4   3   2   0
4       3   2   6   3
5       1   1   1   0
```

I want to query this dataframe to select all the rows that have values **greater** than 1 (V) in **greater** than 2 (C) columns.

In this case, the selected rows would be Index 3 and 4 would be selected as they have values greater than 1 appearing in more than 2 columns viz. Index 3 has 4, 3, 2 (all greater than 1) appearing in A, B, C i.e. 3 columns and similarly, Index 4 has values 3, 2, 6, 3 (all greater than 1) appearing in A, B, C, and D i.e. 4 columns.

Expected output

```
Index   A   B   C   D
----------------------
3       4   3   2   0
4       3   2   6   3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create the following mask to select the rows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[2, 0, 0, 10],
        [0, 3, 6, 0],
        [4, 3, 2, 0],
        [3, 2, 6, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list('ABCD'))
mask = (df.values > 1).sum(axis=1) > 2
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   A  B  C  D
2  4  3  2  0
3  3  2  6  3
```

The main idea of creating the mask is to create an array of boolean values where `True` means the value is above 1, then sum those values across rows and if the sum is above 2, that means there were more than two values above 1.

As an alternative you could use [numpy.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) to create the mask:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[2, 0, 0, 10],
        [0, 3, 6, 0],
        [4, 3, 2, 0],
        [3, 2, 6, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list('ABCD'))
mask = np.count_nonzero(df.values > 1, axis=1) > 2
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   A  B  C  D
2  4  3  2  0
3  3  2  6  3
```